# jQuery change event show on click, swap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the change events to swap on a dropdown menu. If one is hidden, I want it to show when the value matches, and vise versa. Currently, once One is hidden, and the value changes, it remains hidden. Please Help. toggle isnt' working well for me.

```
<label for="filter-select"> Issue Type: </label>
<select class="filter" id="filter-select" name="filtering">
    <option selected="selected">Any</option>
    <option value="incident">Incidents</option>
    <option value="feature">Feature Requests</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(".sort > tr > td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
  var textid = $(this).text();
  $(this).attr('id', textid); 
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(".sort > tr").each(function(){
var ide = $(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').attr('id');
$(this).attr('id', ide);

});   

var username = "dariuscastillo12@qa-team.com"
var password = "DpcMixcolt12!!"  
var formurl = "/api/v2/requests/"+id+".json)";
function make_base_auth(user, password) { 
var tok = user + ':' + password
var hash = btoa(tok);
return "Basic " + hash;
}      

 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: formurl,
 datatype: "json",
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',make_base_auth(username, password));

},
success: function (result) {

$.each(result, function(i, value) {   

$('.filter').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() =='any') {
        $('.sort > tr').each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    }

    if ($(this).val() === 'incident') {
        $('.sort > tr').each(function() {
            if (value.ticket_form_id == '59229' & value.id == $(this).attr('id')) {
                console.log('incident', $(this).attr('id'));
                $(this).toggle();  
            }
        });
     }
    else if ($(this).val() === 'feature') {
        $('.sort > tr').each(function() {
            if (value.ticket_form_id == '39365' & value.id == $(this).attr('id')) {
                console.log('new feature', $(this).attr('id'));
                $(this).toggle();
            }
        });
    }      
   }); 
   }) 
} 
});
});
```

[image]

Comment: whats "One" , is it a select box you are referring to as 'one'?

Comment: Please remember, when element is hidden the javascript wont run on such elements

Comment: When I select Feature Requests, it hides the tickets that meet the requirements of the if statement, But if I select Incidents after selecting Feature Requests, they remain hidden. I want them to swap back.The idea is to only display incidents when the incident option is selected, and only new features when the new features option is selected.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I guess toggle wont work for select options as you are thinking of. I tried hiding the option after it is selected and showing it back when some other option in the select is selected

Comment: This is hiding the option, I just want it to hide the data returned.

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter. Either include the code from the fiddle within your answer, or don't link to the fiddle at all.